# copy directory from one server to another server to different paths using ansible synchronize

Tags: ansible, rsync, ansible-inventory

Copy directory from one  server to another servers to different paths using ansible synchronize.

```
server1 src:  /tmp/bin 

server2 dest: /usr/poc2/bin
server3 dest: /usr/poc3/bin
server4 dest: /usr/poc4/bin
```

i achieved  this with same path but need with different path

Comment: Got this ,by using host variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this using `host variables`